# Add a new sort by option

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-sorting

**I want to create a new sort by option, wich is best sellers... how can i do it ?**

I've found this in the admin but i can't create a new option here...

[image]

Comment: Are you using product attribute for marking a product as best seller?

Comment: @piyush_systematix yes!

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Stores** -> **Attributes** -> **Product**.

Edit desired attribute.

Set **Used for Sorting in Product Listing** to **yes**. Save attribute. Reload Category edit page in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps to create new product attribute with Filter Option.

1. Go to Admin *Panel > Stores > Attributes > Products*
2. Press the *Add New Attribute* button
3. Fill out the *Attribute Properties* section
4. Fill out the *Advanced Attribue Properties*

Choose Yes in *Use in Filter Options* field if you want this attribute to be used while filtering products.

5. Save Attribute